# Responsive slideshow with controls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, slideshow

offtopic: sorry for my bad english.
ontopic: i'm trying to do a responsive slideshow with control in AngularJS (i'm newbie in angular too) and i'm stuck in the part of the control the slides, i got this:

app.js

```
angular.module('slider', [])
  .controller('sliderCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var thumbs = $scope.thumbs = [];
    for(i=1;i<=11;i++) {
      thumbs.push({
        image: 'http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports/' + i
      })
    }
  }])
  .service('thumbService', function() {
    this.resize = function(elem, scope) {
      elem.style.width = scope.containerWidth + 'px';
    }
  })
  .directive('carousel', ['$timeout', '$window', function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      controller: 'sliderCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'carousel.html',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        angular.element($window).on('load resize', function() {
          $timeout(function() {
            scope.containerWidth = elem[0].offsetWidth * 0.25;
          }, 200);
        });
      }
    }
  }])
  .directive('thumbs', ['$window', 'thumbService', function($window, thumbService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'thumbs.html',
      require: '^carousel',
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        thumbService.resize(elem[0], scope);
        scope.$watch('containerWidth', function() {
          thumbService.resize(elem[0], scope);
        });
      }
    };
  }])
  .directive('controls', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      require: '^carousel',
      templateUrl: 'controls.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.goPrev = function() {
          // TODO
        }
        scope.goNext = function() {
          // TODO
        }
      }
    }
  }])
  .run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('thumbs.html', '<div class="slider-gallery_item" ng-transclude></div>');
    $templateCache.put('carousel.html',
      '<div id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">' +
      ' <div class="slider-gallery" ng-transclude></div>' +
      ' <controls></controls>' +
      '</div>');
    $templateCache.put('controls.html',
      ' <div id="slider-controls"> ' +
      '   <div class="slider-gallery_prev" ng-click="goPrev()"><</div>' +
      '   <div class="slider-gallery_next" ng-click="goNext()">></div>' +
      ' </div>');
  })
```

styles.css

```
.slider-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.slider-gallery {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.slider-gallery_item {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.slider-gallery_item img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}

.slider-gallery {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.slider-gallery_prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.slider-gallery_next {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
```

you can see it on http://plnkr.co/edit/25xt9qUvLaaxgYJQRUzJ?p=preview

as you can see, is a bit responsive but now, i have 11 images in total, how i can do to make functional the button next and prev? isn't a tecnical question, is more the method to aplicate to do it,

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your controller you can declare two methods, e.g.:

```
this.goNext = function(){
  $scope.thumbs.push($scope.thumbs.shift());
}

this.goPrev = function(){
  $scope.thumbs.unshift($scope.thumbs.pop());
}
```

Then you can call these methods from your directive's link property (don't forget to add the 4th parameter `ctrl`):

```
directive('controls', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      require: '^carousel',
      templateUrl: 'controls.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.goPrev = function() {
          ctrl.goPrev();
        }
        scope.goNext = function() {
          ctrl.goNext();
        }
      }
    }
  }])
```

Comment: i'll try but seems good

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try to [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html#demo) which is responsive and easy to use. It works well with AngularJs and can be highly customized.

Thanks

Comment: i don't want to use jquery, need one full angular but Owl Carousel do what i want, i will see the code! thank you!